# Screen Space - Overlay Canvas for VR in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, unity-ui

How can I get the effect of Screen Space - Overlay Canvas on VR?

I want both of the eye cameras to have menus in the exact same positions.
I don't want to mix it with world space, so the only option I can think of is having a duplicate of each UI element, one for each camera.

Am I missing a simpler solution?

Comment: Afaik ScreenSpace canvas isn't rendered at all as soon as you go to VR. I also would strongly discourage from trying to achieve this. It would appear to the user in the closest possible "distance" and be extremly exhausting for the eyes to focus anything on it ... what speaks against a worldspace canvas? what is your actual goal you are trying to achieve with that? Maybe Screenspace-Camera is a compromise?

Comment: Yes. You're missing [prefabs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Prefabs.html). All changes from one place will be reflected in other place.

Comment: @derHugo, actually, same position would appear as the most far possible distance, and this is easy for the eyes.
The goal is to add notifications for developers, not for the final product, this is why i prefer to avoid world space, so I could more easily separate this from the scene. and this is also why I'm looking for a very basic solution.

Comment: @user14492, if I understand correctly, prefabs won't help me to duplicate the ui changes at runtime.

Comment: No, not at run time. Only in editor.

Comment: ok, thank you, so this will not be a good solution for me.
I am looking for a dynamic UI solution.

Comment: Truly sad part is that Unreal Engine handles screen space rendering in VR easily. I have used it a lot and am totally baffled that Unity still doesn't implement this. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lxFqUDW5-fE

Comment: Been two years, anyone know if Unity will get this anytime soon?